# how to list without changing order in shell script?

Tags: shell-script, shell, sed

i have a folder full of nc files from 1979 to 2018 daily data. i wish to combine it all to one nc but when i tried to list the files to create a ferret script, the order was changed.i am giving below a sample of the names of my data files.

```
ERA5_2018_9_12_UVP.nc
ERA5_2018_9_13_UVP.nc
ERA5_2018_9_14_UVP.nc
ERA5_2018_9_15_UVP.nc
ERA5_2018_9_16_UVP.nc
ERA5_2018_9_17_UVP.nc
ERA5_2018_9_18_UVP.nc
ERA5_2018_9_19_UVP.nc
ERA5_2018_9_1_UVP.nc
ERA5_2018_9_20_UVP.nc
ERA5_2018_9_21_UVP.nc
ERA5_2018_9_22_UVP.nc
ERA5_2018_9_23_UVP.nc
ERA5_2018_9_24_UVP.nc
```

the dates are changing when i list them i tried a code in shell script to change the name of the files using `sed` command.

```
ls *.nc >temp
    for i in {1..9..1}
    do
    sed "s/_${i}_UVP/_0${i}_/g"
    done < temp
```

can anyone help me in this regard?

Comment: Does `ls *.nc |sort  -t_ -k2 -k3 -k4 -n ` produce the correctly sorted list?

Answer (score 4):

Note that with GNU `ls`, if you pass the `-v` option (*version* sort), those files will be listed in chronological order.

Same if you use the `n` glob qualifier (or the `numericglobsort` option) in `zsh` as in:

```
combine-nc-files ./*.nc(n)
```

Now, for your renaming, you can use `zsh` and do:

```
autoload -Uz zmv # best in ~/.zshrc
zmv -n '(*_<1979-2018>_)(<1-12>)_(<1-31>)(_UVP.nc)' \
       '$1${(l[2][0])2}_${(l[2][0])3}$4'
```

(remove `-n` (dry-run) if happy)

To `l`eft-pad with `0`s to a width of `2` those months and days.

Comment: @meenakshisreejith If you found the answer useful, please consider [accepting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) is to that others facing a similar issue may find it more easily.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is the order of the files. `ls` sorts them alphabetically, but you want them sorted differently.

```
ls *.nc |sort  -t_ -k2 -k3 -k4 -n
```

will tell `sort` to use `_` as field separator and then sort numerically (`-n`) on the second, third and fourth field.

Comment: I rolled back the edits, because they add nothing to the answer in this case. 1) Using `ls -d -- *.nc` instead of just `ls *.nc` does not provide any significant difference in this case. 2) `sort` keydef is `F[.C][OPTS][,F[.C][OPTS]]`; that makes a keydef of `-k2` correct and `-k2,2` unnecessary complexer 3)From the example, you can see that the filenames do not contain new lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import glob
file=[]
arr=[]
for i in glob.glob('*.nc'):
    file.append(i.strip())

for g in file:
    arr.append(g.split('_')[3])
arr.sort()

for er in arr:
    for nh in file:
        p=nh.split('_')[3]
        if (p == er ):
            print nh
```

Tested and worked fine